# How to plot one column on x-axis and use other col as legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to analyse the following data and plot a graph for the same...

Here is data:

```
Labels  Treatments  Reps    Yield
T1  No fertilizer   1   8
T2  Ferti 1         1   12
T3  Ferti 2         1   14
T4  Ferti 3         1   16
T5  Ferti 4         1   18
T6  Ferti 5         1   16
T7  Ferti 6         1   24
T8  Ferti 7         1   22
T9  Ferti 8         1   26
T10 Ferti 9         1   30
T11 Ferti 10        1   32
T1  No fertilizer   2   8.2
T2  Ferti 1         2   12.8
T3  Ferti 2         2   13.8
T4  Ferti 3         2   16.6
T5  Ferti 4         2   18
T6  Ferti 5         2   16.6
T7  Ferti 6         2   25.2
T8  Ferti 7         2   22.5
T9  Ferti 8         2   26.4
T10 Ferti 9         2   31
T11 Ferti 10        2   33.2
T1  No fertilizer   3   7.8
T2  Ferti 1         3   12.4
T3  Ferti 2         3   14.1
T4  Ferti 3         3   16.2
T5  Ferti 4         3   18.8
T6  Ferti 5         3   16.9
T7  Ferti 6         3   26.4
T8  Ferti 7         3   22.5
T9  Ferti 8         3   27
T10 Ferti 9         3   32.3
T11 Ferti 10        3   34.5
```

I want to perform ANOVA using column `Yield ~ Labels` and use column `Treatments` as Legend. Although, I got the out put but its not ordered, I want Labels T1, T2, T3, T4 .... in order in x-axis. When I add `Treatments` as Legend order of x-axis changes. Please, kindly suggest what I'm doing wrong?.

I tried with the following

```
library(readxl)
library(multcompView)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

my_data <- read_excel(choose.files(), sheet = "Yield")
```

converted columns `Labels` and `Treatments` to factors

```
my_data <- read_excel(file.choose(), sheet = 1)

my_data <- my_data |> mutate(Labels = factor(Labels, 
                         labels = c("T1", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", "T6", "T7", "T8", "T9", "T10", "T11"))) |> 
  mutate(Treatments = factor(Treatments, 
                             labels = c("No fertilizer", "Ferti 1","Ferti 2","Ferti 3","Ferti 4","Ferti 5",
                                        "Ferti 6","Ferti 7","Ferti 8","Ferti 9","Ferti 10")))

yield_aov <- aov(Yield ~ Labels, data = my_data)

yield_aov1 <- anova(yield_aov)

tukey_L <- TukeyHSD(yield_aov)

tukey_letters <- multcompLetters4(yield_aov, tukey_L)

table_yield <- my_data %>% group_by(Labels) %>% 
  summarise(Average = mean(Yield), .groups = 'drop')

myletters <- as.data.frame.list(tukey_letters$Labels)

table_yield$Letters <- myletters$Letters

table_yield <- arrange(table_yield, Labels)

table_yield %>% ggplot(aes(Labels, Average, fill = Labels)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour = "black", width = 0.5) + 
  labs(x = "Treatments", 
       y = "Yield (q/ha)")
```

When I plot graph with `Labels` and `Yield` its plotting correct But when I add Treatment column as legend order of x-axis changes.

```
table_yield %>% ggplot(aes(Labels, Average, fill = Labels)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour = "black", width = 0.5) + 
  labs(x = "Treatments", 
       y = "Yield") + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = unique(my_data$Treatments))
```

How to assign T1 as No Fertilizers, T2 as Ferti 1... so on in plots?. Kindly help. Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please provide your data using `dput()`, as it appears you are lacking a column name in your initial table.